# Сортировка LINQ ThenBy в цикле

Tags: c#, сортировка, циклы, linq

Почему получается разный результат в переменной **gg**?

1. Вариант

   ```
   var kk = ff.OrderBy(el => el.path[0]);

   for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
         {
             kk = kk
                 .ThenBy(el => el.path.Length > i
                 ? el.path[i]
                 : 0);
         }

   var gg = kk.ToList();
   ```
2. Вариант

   ```
   var kk = ff.OrderBy(el => el.path[0]);

   kk = kk
    .ThenBy(el => el.path.Length > 1
    ? el.path[1]
    : 0);

   kk = kk
    .ThenBy(el => el.path.Length > 2
     ? el.path[2]
     : 0);

   var gg = kk.ToList();
   ```

Comment: ThenBy??? его надо использовать последовательно, а не в новом операторе

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev необязательно в новом, `kk` в данном случае [`IOrderedEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534852.aspx)  и поддерживает `ThenBy`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Переменная `i` захватывается лямбда-выражением:

```
kk = kk
          .ThenBy(el => el.path.Length > i
          ? el.path[i]
          : 0);
```

, которое компилятор воспринимает как: «возьми переменную `i`, запомни ее, и когда лямбда будет вызвана используй значение `i` на тот момент».

Выполняться выражение будет при обработке последовательности в строке:

```
var gg = kk.ToList();
```

, которая находится после цикла. В этот момент `i` содержит значение 3.

Исправить можно, создав отдельную переменную для лямбды, значение которой изменяться не будет:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
    var lambdaValue = i;
    kk = kk
          .ThenBy(el => el.path.Length > lambdaValue 
          ? el.path[lambdaValue]
          : 0);
```

Вообще хорошим тоном считается не использовать в LINQ изменяемые переменные.

Ошибку можно воспроизвести на более простом примере:

```
var i = 1;
//последовательность из одной единицы
var sequence = Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(val => i);   
//что-то делаем с переменной
i = 1000;
//Ожидание: 1
Console.WriteLine(sequence.First());
//Реальность: 1000
```

Comment: этот баг вроде как исправен в VS2015 (c# 6)

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev это не баг, код делает то что ему сказано :) соответственно, не исправлен.

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev: В C#5 изменено поведение для `foreach`. Поведение для нормального `for` не поменялось -- например, потому, что переменная цикла могла быть объявлена и _вне_ цикла!